# How can I delete photos from Google Workspace account storage space?

Tags: storage, photo

I have erroneously backed up all my photos to my workspace account storage which is now full. I need to delete these photos but cannot find any instructions in the Admin console to do this. Thanks to anyone who can assist me! - Dominic

I was not able to try anything as I could not find instructions in Google Workspace admin console for my account.